# Regex for leading numbers and space with string

Tags: regex

I have strings with leading numbers and space like this

123 Text

1234 Text

12345 Text

I like to remove the leading numbers from the strings with regex.  The result should be

Text

Text

Text

Comment: Check the update of my answer, I forgot the caret which only makes it match at the beginning of lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. Spent many hours to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^[\d ]*` replace with `''` -> would do on most regex flavors.

You might have to indicate multiple line mode, as explained in the Text Pad [regex faq](http://jeffyepstein.com/docs/code/textpad/regex_faq.html) on their website.  Ironically enough it doesn't seem to say which flavor they support.

Jan Govaerts made an excellent [reference website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for plenty of flavors, and there is also a [reference work](http://regex.info/) written by Friedl.

Comment: I use Text Pad for this

Comment: Works better in Notepad++